# PHP - Write to database and remove after set time

Tags: php, mysql

Basically when a user wishes to recover their password, I generate a hash and store it in a MySQL Database. I do not want this hash to exist forever though, but to be removed from the database after say 5 minutes.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Also if anyone has any ideas about implementing password recovery in a different way I would love to hear.

Thanks in advance, Tom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next to the hash, store a date with it. Whenever that date is in the past, the recovery key doesn't work anymore.

No need to actually delete the key then

*edit based on comments:*

*You should run a cronjob every now and then. For example once a day, to delete the keys not used, and already expired.*

Comment: Sure there is, database maintenance is also important. He should still have a cron job or something to remove all keys which are past the current date every night.

Comment: And if you do want to delete the key, you can just run a query every few minutes that deletes keys which have passed their expiration date.

Comment: If you take this approach you also would be able to track how often someone tries to recover a password (depending on the data structure), which might help you identify attacks on your application / track down where intrusions have occurred.

Comment: if you would be so kind to actually approve the answer :)

Comment: approved now, had to wait 10 minutes to accept. Thanks for the info about cron.

Comment: No need for a cron job. Just add the deletion code to where the "is this a valid key" check is done. If that code finds that the key is invalid/expired, you can delete the key right then and there, without the overhead of a cron job doing a needless delete query every 10 minutes or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to install the APC cache (which has many other benefits) and simply set the key-value pair to expire in the desired amount of time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was looking at APC and it's probably something i'm going to add to the system in the future, just looking for a quick fix atm :)